# ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(668)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute error using ActionChains from Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, egl

when i run the code:

```
for i in elementsList:
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(i).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

It works (yes) & echo back this error:

```
[0125/121353.774: ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(668)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
```

the number "121353.774" is not const, it increases every round

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(668)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
```

...is a *DEBUG* message which implies that there was an error with one of the [GL Switches](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/gl/gl_switches.cc?q=kGLImplementationEGLName&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=13)

---

This error is defined in [gl_surface_egl.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/ui/gl/gl_surface_egl.cc#674) as follows:

```
static void EGLAPIENTRY LogEGLDebugMessage(EGLenum error,
                       const char* command,
                       EGLint message_type,
                       EGLLabelKHR thread_label,
                       EGLLabelKHR object_label,
                       const char* message) {
  std::string formatted_message = std::string("EGL Driver message (") +
                  GetDebugMessageTypeString(message_type) +
                  ") " + command + ": " + message;
```

---

### Deep Dive

The argument [`--use-gl`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/gl/gl_switches.cc?q=kUseGL&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=97) selects which implementation of GL the GPU process should be used and the available options are:

- *desktop*: whatever desktop OpenGL the user has installed (Linux and Mac default).
- *egl*: whatever EGL / GLES2 the user has installed (Windows default - actually ANGLE).
- *swiftshader*: The SwiftShader software renderer.

This *DEBUG* message is not harmful and you can continue with your tests.

---

### Additional consideration

However as per best practices, if your usecase involves invoking `click()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(i).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

In your usecase as you are creating a *List* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` as follows:

```
for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "elements_css"))):
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(i).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

> PS: `121353.774` in `0125/121353.774` is the partial timestamp

---

### Outro

Possibly this error is caused by the app getting launched by `ES2-only` devices, even though the manifest requires `ES`3 capability. Updating `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE` from `EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT` to **`EGL_OPENGL_ES3_BIT`** will solve this issue.